# Azure Pipeline: 'Microsoft.Build.Locator' - An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (dnt.deps.json)

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running the following script https://github.com/RicoSuter/Namotion.Reflection/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml for a CI build demo:

```
trigger:
  branches:
      include:
      - master
      - release
      - refs/tags/*
pr:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: Release
  Projects: '**/*.csproj'

steps:
# Install required SDKs and tools
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '2.2.203'

# Patch preview project versions (only when on master branch)
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install DNT'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  inputs:
    script: 'npm i -g dotnettools'
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Update project version patch'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  inputs:
    script: 'dnt bump-versions patch'
    failOnStderr: true
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Patch project version preview'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  inputs:
    script: 'dnt bump-versions preview "$(Build.BuildNumber)"'
    failOnStderr: true

# Build and test
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(Projects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(Projects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect "Code Coverage"'
    publishTestResults: true
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

# Publish artifacts
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy packages'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  inputs:
    Contents: '**/*.nupkg'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I tried to adjust the vmImage to use `ubuntu-latest` and adjusted the npm command so that it is prefixed with 'sudo', however on the command dnt bump-versions patch I get the error below:

```
##[section]Starting: Update project version patch
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
dnt bump-versions patch
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/29d33702-3084-4704-851f-a6f76f18f813.sh
DNT (DotNetTools) NPM CLI
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (dnt.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Build.Locator', version: '1.2.6'
    path: 'lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.Build.Locator.dll'
child_process.js:660
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: dotnet "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dotnettools/bin/binaries/NetCore22/dnt.dll" bump-versions patch
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/dotnettools/bin/dnt.js:52:11
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:286:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  status: 140,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3784,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.
##[section]Finishing: Update project version patch
```

Any ideas please? I am following this code from a tutorial, I am open to other yaml scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you faced indeed caused by `dotnettools`.

See this [DNT#npm-cli-package](https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT#npm-cli-package). You can see that the requirement of `dotnettool` is

> .NET Core 2.2+ or NetFX 4.7.2 and Visual Studio 2019

**BUT,**

`NetFX` is the one which unique for `windows`. In another word, if you continue want to use dotnettool, you can not use `Ubuntu` and `MacOs` image because `NetFX` is **Windows-only**.

So, here you can not apply the pipeline with Ubuntu agent.